# Mongoose.find() can't find an element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to find and update WEEKDATA that has a specific WEEKNUM.

Schema:

```
{
    ageGroup:String,
    monthData: [{
        month:String,

        weekData : [{
             weekNum : String,
             theme   : String,
        }]
    }]
}
```

This is how I am trying to do it but it can't find WEEKNUM inside the document and instead of updating WEEKDATA, it just creates a new document which is not required:

```
var timeTable; // CONTAINS JSON SENT BY THE CLIENT (EXACTLY THE SAME AS SCHEMA)
TimeTable.getTimeTableModelObject().findOne(
    {
        ageGroup: timeTable.ageGroup, 
        month: timeTable.monthData.month, 
        weekNum: timeTable.monthData.weekData.weekNum
    }, function(err, foundData){
        if(err) {
            console.error("error in inserting TimeTableController.js ", err);
            return;
        }
        saveOrUpdateWeek();
    }
);

function saveOrUpdateWeek() {
    var weekData = timeTable.monthData.weekData;
    TimeTable.getTimeTableModelObject().findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            ageGroup: timeTable.ageGroup, 
            month: timeTable.monthData.month, 
            weekNum: timeTable.monthData.weekData.weekNum
        }, 
        weekData, 
        { upsert: true }, 
        function(err, foundData){
            if(err) {
                console.error("error in inserting TimeTableController.js ", err);
                return;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I update the WEEKDATA which contains a specific WEEKNUM?

**EDIT:**

**timeTable** Object contains this

```
{
        ageGroup:"2",
        monthData: [
            {
                month:"Jan",
                weekData : [{
                    weekNum : "1",
                    theme   : "circleTime theme weekly 2",
                }]
            },
            {
                 month:"Feb",
                 weekData : [{
                    weekNum : "2",
                    theme   : "circleTime theme weekly 2"
                 }]
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Shouldn't the function `saveOrUpdateWeek();` need parameters to find and update the record?

Comment: For testing purposes I have made the timeTable object as global and it contains the JSON (similar to schema). The parameters to find and update are in the query argument of the `TimeTable.getTimeTableModelObject().findOneAndUpdate()`

Comment: @JimmyPaul any ideas please?

Comment: inside `saveOrUpdateWeek` what is `timetable`? There's bits of code missing from this question

Comment: Please see the updated the question. I have mentioned that timeTable Contains data we need to insert in the collection

Comment: Can you post the timeTable object?

Comment: I am updating the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having issues accessing the object because you are using an schema that utilizes an array of objects, not just objects. try accessing the values by their index first. For example:

```
var timeTable = {
    ageGroup:"2",
    monthData: [
        {
            month:"Jan",
            weekData : [{
                weekNum : "1",
                theme   : "circleTime theme weekly 2",
            }]
        },
        {
             month:"Feb",
             weekData : [{
                weekNum : "2",
                theme   : "circleTime theme weekly 2"
             }]
        }
    ]
}

console.log(data.monthData[0].weekData[0]) -> { weekNum: '1', theme: 'circleTime theme weekly 2' }

console.log(data.monthData[0].weekData[0].weekNum) - > 1
```